# Busca de endereço no google maps e retorna CEP com 5 digitos

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google

Fiz um dragger no google maps, que movendo o marker pra rua, ele retorna todos os dados da rua/av/travessa etc.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte :

- Tem alguns endereço que retorna 5 digitos, isso é normal ?
- Como geralmente vocês tratam o endereço com CEP de 5 digitos ?]

> Exemplo : Buscando por esse endereço :  Avenida Alexandre Mackenzie
>   Ele me retorna esse cep : 05322

O que faço de errado na busca ?

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({latLng: pos}, function(responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                marker.formatted_address = responses[0].formatted_address;
                console.log(responses[0]);
                for(var i in responses[0].address_components){
                    if (typeof(responses[0].address_components[i]) === "object" && responses[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "street_number") {
                        if (typeof responses[0].address_components[i].short_name != undefined){
                            $('#end_numero').val(responses[0].address_components[i].short_name);
                        }
                    } else if (typeof(responses[0].address_components[i]) === "object" && responses[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "route") {
                        if (typeof responses[0].address_components[i].long_name != undefined){
                            $('#end_rua').val(String(responses[0].address_components[i].long_name.toUpperCase()).replace("'", ""));
                        }
                    } else if (typeof(responses[0].address_components[i]) === "object" && responses[0].address_components[i].types[2] == "sublocality_level_1") {
                        if (typeof responses[0].address_components[i].short_name != undefined){
                            $('#end_bairro').val(String(responses[0].address_components[i].short_name.toUpperCase()).replace("'", "").substring(0,30));
                        }
                    } else if (typeof(responses[0].address_components[i]) === "object" && responses[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "locality") {
                        if (typeof responses[0].address_components[i].long_name != undefined){
                            $('#end_cidade').val(responses[0].address_components[i].long_name.toUpperCase());
                        }
                    } else if (typeof(responses[0].address_components[i]) === "object" && responses[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "postal_code") {
                        if (typeof responses[0].address_components[i].long_name != undefined){
                            $('#end_cep').val(responses[0].address_components[i].long_name.toUpperCase());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                marker.formatted_address = 'Não é possivel localizar o endereço.';
            }
            infowindow.setContent(marker.formatted_address + "<br>Coordenadas: " + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```

Obrigado.

Emerson

Comment: O código do JS que esta retornando o cep seria bem-vindo. Porém, sem uma analise maior, acho que você poderia simplesmente adicionar 000 quando retornar 5 dígitos.

Comment: o código do js é esse :

Comment: isso aconteceu comigo em ceps que terminam com "000". Eu apenas verifico se retornou apenas 5 numero e completo com 000, mas se vc testar os ceps eles não estão errados.